# Correct way to get child nodes using HtmlAgilityPack in C#

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data with HtmlAgilityPack. However it is not working as I expected. Each web page I'm scraping contains a list of items, and each item contains first name and email.

```
<div class="item">
    <div>...
    <span class="first-name"></span></div>
    <div>...
    <span class="email"></span></div>
</div>
```

My thought was to extract all div nodes from each page, then retrieve first name and email from each node. I thought this would be working:

```
var div = rootDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='item']");
var firstNames = div.SelectNodes("//span[@class='first-name']//text()");
var emails = div.SelectNodes("//span[@class='email-address']//a//text()");
```

However, firstNames and emails seemed to retrieve all nodes in the page, not the div. I only want to get child nodes belong to one div. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `//` double slash for the root entry point, `/` single slash for child.

Comment: I changed to single slash but it returned null this time. How can I get nodes only if they are children of the div node?

Comment: Let me make sure of one thing, you want to list all names and emails inside the `div` with `class="item"` or you want to list the first entry of each?

Comment: the div with class="item" represents a single entry, so it should only contain one first name and email. A page may contain indefinite numbers of div with class="item" elements

Comment: I just figured out the correct way: .//span[@class='given-name']/text() this gives me the child node. Thanks so much for answering!